# Custom ActionMailer delivery method not called from rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actionmailer

I'm trying to write an rspec test that will send an email using my custom delivery method for ActionMailer.

My custom delivery method implementation:

```
class MyCustomDeliveryMethod  

  def deliver!(message)
    puts 'Custom deliver for message: ' + message.to_s
    ...
  end
```

Rspec code:

```
it "should send an email" do
  WebMock.allow_net_connect!
  ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method( :api, MyCustomDeliveryMethod)
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true

  puts 'expecting this to call my custom delivery method'

  ActionMailer::Base.mail( :to => 'me@example.com',
    :subject => 'here is a test subject sent by ActionMailer',
    :body => 'here is a test body sent by <i>ActionMailer</i>',
    :delivery_method => :api 
  )

end
```

test.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :api
```

However I never see the 'custom deliver' string. My other tests exercise the other methods of the class fine, it's just the triggering of the deliver!() method doesnt work. What am I missing?

(NB. there are a few examples around of testing ActionMailers with rspec, however they seem to refer to mocking the mailer behaviour, which is not what I want - I want the actual email to go out).

Comment: your `MyCustomMailer` mailer should be inherited from standart `ActionMailer::Base`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got there in the end. There were two things missing:

The custom delivery class must define an initialise method that takes one parameter. e.g.

```
def initialize(it)
end
```

You need to `.deliver_now` the mail to get it to trigger, so the full calling code is e.g.

```
it "should send an email" do
  WebMock.allow_net_connect!
  ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method( :api, MyCustomDeliveryMethod)
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true

  puts 'expecting this to call my custom delivery method'

  ActionMailer::Base.mail( :to => 'me@example.com',
    :subject => 'here is a test subject sent by ActionMailer',
    :body => 'here is a test body sent by <i>ActionMailer</i>',
    :delivery_method => :api 
  ).deliver_now

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but I think the problem is that your `MyCustomMailer` class is not inherited from `ActionMailer::Base`.

Check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer) docs.
Here `ApplicationMailer` is inherited from `ActionMailer::Base` and used to set some default values.

And actual mailer class `UserMailer` is inherited from `ApplicationMailer`.
If you like you can skip extra class and inherit directly, i.e

```
class MyCustomMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  ...
end
```

Comment: Sorry I updated the comments to clarify that this is a custom delivery method, not a custom mailer.